# Will a flash player plugin be needed for internet video in 18.04?

Tags: video, flash, streaming, adobe, 18.04

I know some websites still ask for flash being installed, like for a chess playing site.

[image]

But in Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 (at the date I am posting less than a week before becoming stable) **without a flashplayer plugin being installed at system level** (no `adobe-flashplugin`,`flashplugin-installer` or `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`), while the [Adobe flash test](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/) is not passed, **all the videos I have tested online (Tweeter videos, Vimeo, live streams on youtube, etc) play just fine** in all main browsers (Firefox, Chromium, Google Chrome, Opera).

Will such plugins be needed anymore in Ubuntu for videos? What is the situation? Some other plugin is installed at system level? Are plugins only present within the browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you answered the question yourself. Some sites still require Flash, and to access contents there you need Flash irrespective of which OS version you are using.

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html) in the Ubuntu Desktop Guide applies to Budgie as well.

Comment: My question is not whether there are flash videos on the internet, but whether Ubuntu 18.04 still needs that plugin ( any of `adobe-flashplugin flashplugin-installer  pepperflashplugin-nonfree`) to play them. I don't seem to have any installed by default and all internet video plays fine in all main browsers. - At the same time on an ubuntu 16.04 -based system, some of my browsers cannot play a lot of flash out there even with those plugins.

Comment: I can confirm that I do not have installed any of the packages mentioned at the link posted in your answer (browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash, adobe-flashplugin, flashplugin-installer), nor other flash-related package.

Comment: @cipricus: Yes, Ubuntu 18.04 - just like any OS out there - still needs Flash to be able to view contents on sites which require it. Many web services which previously required Flash don't do so any longer. YouTube is one example. I don't think there is much more to say on this general level. I you have a more specific problem you need help to sort, please ask a new question.

Comment: But how come none of the aforementioned packages relating to flash are installed on my system while I have no problem playing flash streams?

Comment: @cipricus: It's possible to install Flash in other ways. But how about providing a URL to an example of a resource which requires Flash and which you found you can stream from without it.